# mp4 video in mysql database as "blob"

Tags: php, mysql

I have read several forums that advise against storing videos in a database.  I unfortunately am forced to do so based on constraints for a school project I am working on.  I was wondering if someone would let me know where I am going wrong when trying to store my video into the database.  We are using an embedded procedure(someone else in my group wrote them that may be the problem)but after retrieving the video from the form it is returned as an Array which contains the name, type, error, location, etc(things associated with the video). After retrieving the array from the form I naively tried to insert the whole thing into the data based via function call through a query as seen below.  This gives an immediate error "Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list' ".  I get that Array is the type of `$video` after we pull it from the form but I'm not sure where  to go from there.

```
if(empty($_FILES['sonogram'])) {
    echo 'The file exceeded maximum';
}
else {
    $video = $_FILES['sonogram'];
}

//call our embedded procedure to add the video to the database
mysql_query("call SaveImage($studyId, $video, 'nothing new')");
```

Could anyone just let me know if I am making a simple error(syntax, etc..) or if there is something missing due to working with the blob/mp4.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$_FILES is basically just an information array. It doesn't contain your actual file. You will need to open the file, read the content and then save it to the database.

Never tested the following, especially with videos:

```
// Read the video file content from the temp file.
// Usually on uploads you move the file.
$video = file_get_contents($_FILES['sonogram']['tmp_name']);
```

Comment: I think this works to get the video but it still will not insert into the database

Comment: Is SaveImage a store routine? Couldn't you just do something like `INSERT INTO my_table(my_id, my_video, my_title) VALUES('$id', '$video', '$title');`? (Be careful for SQL injections)

Comment: Yes saveImage is a stored routine(not my idea) I tried inserting via a direct query as you suggested but get an error that says You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: According to your logic, if the video doesn't get uploaded, you still call mysql_query and try to insert nothing as the video. Is the studyID declared? Did you try wrapping variables with quote in your query? You should try as @lvaro-g-vicario mentionned, using mysql_real_escape trying with $video. -EDIT- If you're not using quotes in your query and try to insert a blank variable, it's normal that it says near ''.

Comment: I have narrowed it down to the $video being the problem If I just pass it an empty string It does add too the data base but not with $video

Answer (score 0):

You have two entirely different and mostly unrelated tasks here: upload a file and pass it to your procedure.

- The first one is explained in the [Handling file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) chapter of the PHP manual.
- The second one depends on what `SaveImage` expects: the file stream or a temporary file name. Since you are using the [legacy mysql extension](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php), which as far as I know does not provide specific support for BLOBs of binary columns, you'll have to inject the video into your SQL query with [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string). If your procedure expects the actual video contents, the query will probably exceed the maximum package size and will crash.